# Running Javascript on Chrome from outside console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How do I run Javascript on a website that is opened using Chrome but not using Chrome's console.

I'm trying to open gmail --> All mail --> open each email. I already wrote the code and it is successfully working when I run it on the Chrome console. But is there a way to run this script outside of the chrome console?

Comment: For clarification, you want to run JS on a website without using chrome DevTools, correct?

Answer (score -1):

Look into Tamper Monkey, this will be ideal for your description.

It allows you to execute your own JavaScript on any domain you desire.

If you're doing this for any malicious purpose, stop.